# Write a Java program that downloads the first 100 comics of the webcomic XKCD. Be sure to use https:// for all URLS

Tags: java, file, download, src

This is what I have so far, and I am having trouble downloading 1-100 comics starting at https://xkcd.com/1/ and I know I am supposed to be going to the source code for the website. However, I cant seem to figure out how to get all the first 100 comics into my designated file I set it to save to. For example, I want https://xkcd.com/1/(view-source:https://xkcd.com/1/), https://xkcd.com/2/(view-source:https://xkcd.com/2/), and all the way up to comic 100. I know the img src is at line 50, but once again I don't know how to approach it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL imgURL = null;
    for (int web = 1; web <= 100; web++) {
    try {
        imgURL = new URL("https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/barrel_cropped_(1).jpg");
        InputStream stream = imgURL.openStream();
        Files.copy(stream, Paths.get("file/WebComics" + web + ".png"));
        System.out.println("Done!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I forgot to mention that all of the downloads are of the same picture from the first comic, but I need them to download all of the them up to 100 comics.

Comment: Curious, is this homework question? Seems like all you really need is HTTPConnection and parse the resulting HTML (not jump to line 50 but really parse).

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer How would i go about parse the resulting HTML?

Comment: Use a library like jsoup or something. Going to line 50 is not going to help if they change their page layout. Get the page title and then search for the `img` tag that contains `alt` same as the page title and pull out the `src` attribute. That's the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jsoup library jar to your project, and then try this:

```
static void do_page(int id) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://xkcd.com/" + id).get();
    Elements imgs = doc.select("#comic img");
    for (Element e: imgs) {
        System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
    }
}
```

Then call the `do_page` function in a loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    do_page(i);
}
```

Now, instead of  printing it, you can use JSoup again to probably download the images like you see fit.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense! Thank you!